# SELECT total sales, total active customers, avg. spend per customer, avg. spend per transaction for 2018 and 2019, respectively?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this block of data

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXApR1qr7nQhcg5t2Tuxkx/1

[image]

So I would like to obtain the total sales,total active customers ,average spend per customer and avg spend per transaction in ONE SQL query.

Is this possible to do?

Here is the query that I have done but the subquery is not working for me.
Please help.

```
select year(transdate) as year,truncate(sum(price * quantity),2) AS totalsales,COUNT(DISTINCT(b.custid)) as activecustomers,

SELECT truncate(AVG(total),2) AS AVERAGE 
FROM (SELECT custid, sum(price*quantity) AS total 
      FROM transaction GROUP BY custid) A
    ;

from transaction 
where transdate >= '2018-01-01' and transdate <= '2019-12-31'
group by YEAR(transdate)
```

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? (We need both anyway, a [mcve].)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT b.custid)` to make code clearer - for everyone!

Comment: Column transdate data type?

Comment: ?? you can't have select...select and there is a sudden terminator in the middle of the code block. please edit to match the fiddle code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question -> the total sales, total active customers, average spend per customer and avg spend per transaction in ONE SQL query.

`select  sum(price*quantity) as total_sales, count(distinct custid) as 'active user', sum(price*quantity)/count(distinct custid) as 'avg spend per customer', sum(price*quantity)/count(transid) as 'avg spend per transition' from transaction`